# Pipreqs: SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+FEFF

Tags: python, pip

When I try to run `pipreqs /path/to/project` it comes back with

```
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    # !/usr/bin/env python3
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+FEFF
```

my project contains a number of files and all of them contain their own imports. I read somewhere that it could be an issue to create a requirements.txt for a number of files so I tried to move the main file into a new dir and run pipreqs on there but again no success.

my imports look like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#######################################################
# Initialise Wikipedia agent
#######################################################
import requests
import json
import aiml
import wikipedia
import numpy as np
from nltk.sem.logic import *
from nltk.inference.resolution import *
from nltk.inference import ResolutionProver
from nltk.inference.nonmonotonic import *
from nltk import *
from nltk.sem import logic
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

Anyone has any ideas on what it could be? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Edit:

Forgot to specify: Running `Python 3.9.10` and `pipreqs` was installed using `pip3`

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Your file contains a Unicode byte-order mark.  Some services don't like that.  In what editor did you create this?

Comment: Save the files as UTF with no BOM and try again, or use another encoding. You are possible running python 2.7? Run `python --version` if you don't know.

Comment: @TimRoberts Running macOS - I tried removing it but with no success. Using VS Code. Also tried to run pipreqs through terminal. I have also tried to run `pipreqs --encoding utf-8 path/to/project` and `pipreqs --force path/to/project`

Comment: @Grismar sorry should have specified running python 3.9.10 - also installed pipreqs using `pip3`

Comment: @Grismar life saver! saving with no BOM worked!! If you would like to answer the question I'll mark it as answered for anyone else in need :D

Comment: Glad you got it!  For anyone else looking at this, I was just going to suggest that running this command on a file will show you what's really at the front of it: `od -x -N 10 <file path>`

Comment: An unfortunate incompatibility between Windows and the rest of the world.  Most modern software will assume a file is encoded with UTF-8.  Not Windows, it will assume some old fashioned code page for backwards compatibility reasons.  The convention Microsoft came up with to mark a file as UTF-8 is to put a U+FEFF character (Zero Width No-Break Space) at the front of the file. It's the most harmless Unicode character you could come up with, but it still confuses some software.

Comment: You could also try using `utf-8-sig` instead of `utf-8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character U+FEFF is the byte order marker, or BOM.

You can save a text file in UTF encoding with or without BOM, and the error message seems to suggest your system can deal with UTF, but doesn't like the BOM, so you should try rewriting the file without BOM.

Alternatively, there's ways to tell Python to expect a different encoding on the command line with environment variables, but I wouldn't go there unless you absolutely must and have no control over the encoding of the file yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point that @MarkRansom solution from the comment under the question also can possibly save a lot of pain (like in my case). So, if `--encoding=utf-8` still does not help, you should try `--encoding=utf-8-sig`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Windows? Your file contains a Unicode byte-order mark. Some services don't like that.  If you remove the BOM, it should work.